# php jQuery ajax call to view image from database

Tags: php, ajax

I have loaded following page (processor.php) table from database. When I click on links, it connects to solve.php for downloading or viewing via GET and particular Id. 
When I click "Download", no issue, image downloads while stay on processor.php

- Problem: When I click "View", page displays on separate page.
- Requirement: I want to display image preview on the same page.
- My idea: To use jQuery Ajax function.
- My Question: Should I remove a href. tag in processor.php and instead what tag should be used to use within Ajax function?

In Ajax function, I have mentioned "?" mark that don't know how to process data. Please complete it?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#?????????").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "solve.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: ?????,

            success: function(data){ //function to be called if request succeeds
                $("#preview").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE Upload(
Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Type VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
SizeMB DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
Content LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);
```

**processor.php**

```
$query = "SELECT Id,Name,Type,SizeMB FROM Upload"; // Good practice. Do not process much data here. leave Content field
$result = mysqli_query ( $con, $query) or die ("Couldn't execute SELECT query: ". mysqli_error($con));
$nrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo '<table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Id</td>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>Type</td>
                            <td>Size (MB)</td>
                        </tr>';
$selfpg = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){
    extract($row);
    echo "<tr>
                            <td>$Id</td>
                            <td>$Name</td>
                            <td>$Type</td>
                            <td>$SizeMB</td>
                            <td> <a href='solve.php?id=$Id'> Download </a> </td>
                            <td> <a href='solve.php?id=$Id&view=preview'> View </a> </td>
                      </tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

***Program code for @BeS with SQL script***

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=51687103902659541890

Answer (score 1):

In your html add a class to links

```
<a class="image-view" href='solve.php?id=$Id&view=preview'>
```

In the javascript, find all elements containing this class, and get the href attribute of the clicked one.

```
$(".image-view").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr('href'); // Get href attribute of current element
    $.ajax({
        url: url, // Use url with arguments
        type: "GET",

        success: function(data){ //function to be called if request succeeds
            $("#preview").html(data); // It should be html here
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ,Sir I tested your solution @Bes . But it is not working. Can I upload the file so that you can check it once? Thanks

Comment: Well, it solves the parts with question marks. But still, in the success function you should do the right things. The `#preview` element is not given, nor the `solve.php` ...

Comment: sir, i put the link on my post. have a look at. please mention what is the wrong I have done. thanks